# How to return ordered by date QuerySet with unique field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a news aggregator based on Django REST + PostgreSQL. In my view I want to return distincted by *link* articles (source, title, text, link fields) and sorted by *import_date* desc. Here is my code:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """list of news by subscription for authorised users only"""
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """filter news by current user subscriptions"""
        subs = self.request.user.profile.subscriptions
        return Article.objects.filter(source__in=subs) \
                              .order_by('-import_date', 'link') \
                              .distinct('import_date', 'link') \

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """news with preview text when listing"""
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ArticleListSerializer
        return ArticleSerializer
```

So I expect to get the list of unique articles sorted by date desc. But my query works only for 'import_date', links not unique. If I swap positions:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """filter news by current user subscriptions"""
    subs = self.request.user.profile.subscriptions
    return Article.objects.filter(source__in=subs) \
                          .order_by('link, '-import_date') \
                          .distinct('link', 'import_date') \
```

Then sorting by date doesn't work. I concluded that distinct works with only one parameter.

My question: how to finally get my unique list of articles sorted by date? Don't understand how to make distinct() work for 2 values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Any fields used in an order_by() call are included in the SQL SELECT columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in conjunction with distinct(). If you order by fields from a related model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are being returned.